# Anyone have ever had this error trying to open workbook in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I get this error from visual studio debug when opening a excel workbook. My workbook has lots of macros and sheets in one workbook. It tries to open then goes to not responding:

OS:W10
Excel Version: 1808 build 10730.20102

> 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sysfer.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>   PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\microsoft
>   shared\ClickToRun\AppvIsvSubsystems32.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>   PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\C2R32.dll'. Cannot find
>   or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\Mso20win32client.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\Mso30win32client.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\Mso40UIwin32client.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.15063.1324_none_b95cd17f98b8affb\GdiPlus.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\Mso50win32client.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\Mso98win32client.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.1155_none_8874c8f83e239b31\comctl32.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winsta.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>   PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>   PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usermgrcli.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10warp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netprofm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\RICHED20.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\npmproxy.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\normaliz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winhttp.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msIso.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'. Cannot find or open
>   the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\webio.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sppc.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\Office16\OART.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\schannel.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mskeyprotect.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncryptsslp.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\webservices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dpapi.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\ADAL.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneCoreCommonProxyStub.dll'. Cannot find or open
>   the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vaultcli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Web.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xmllite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cabinet.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSOHEV.DLL'. Cannot find or
>   open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\networkexplorer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drprov.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntlanman.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\davclnt.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\davhlpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netutils.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\srvcli.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wkscli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netapi32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sfc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sfc_os.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\Csi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\ACEOLEDB.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdart.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\ACECORE.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\1033\ACEWSTR.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\ACEES.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\VBAJET32.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\SystemX86\msvcr100.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mlang.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\EXPSRV.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\coml2.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\hlink.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscobj.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\Office16\GFX.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DataExchange.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dcomp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\Office16\CHART.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemprox.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbemcomn.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemsvc.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\fastprox.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>   PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.15063.1058_none_d70a397c3a350526\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gpapi.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptnet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll'. Cannot find
>   or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBEUI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\1033\VBE7INTL.DLL'. Module was built without
>   symbols. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\SystemX86\FM20.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\directmanipulation.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>   PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10_1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10_1core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Globalization.dll'. Cannot find or open
>   the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BCP47Langs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\globinputhost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE16\MSPTLS.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ExplorerFrame.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\policymanager.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\linkinfo.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSOARIA.DLL'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'EXCEL.EXE' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll'. Cannot find
>   or open the PDB file. The thread 0x540 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x281c has exited with code 0 (0x0). Unhandled exception at
>   0x52A326DF (msvcr100.dll) in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation
>   writing location 0x00000000.

```
The program '[9872] EXCEL.EXE' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here is the event viewer log:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.10730.20102, time stamp: 0x5b938e29
Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.40219.325, time stamp: 0x4d5f0c22
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000026df
Faulting process id: 0xbc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d44c32264b0a46
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.dll
Report Id: f0bdd878-9af4-4b3a-8534-e3bd6874776a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.10730.20102, time stamp: 0x5b938e29
Faulting module name: VBE7.DLL, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b2d80cb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00090d80
Faulting process id: 0xbc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d44c32264b0a46
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL
Report Id: 086ec024-322c-42c9-85f8-3afb6c242621
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Do you get that error when you open Excel without opening that workbook?

Comment: No, I get this opening the workbook only. If I open this on office 2007, it opens fine, if i open this on a previous build lets say 1807, it open fine, seems like it's stuck on the current build. If I open it on a previous build, and recompile my code, then save, I then can open it back on the build it initially got the error.

Comment: I had microsoft open it on the same build and version, and they were able to open it. I'm just wondering why it wouldn't open on my system and other users here as well.

Comment: I have never seen such an error. You could try to export and then reimport all of the modules. VBA projects *can* become corrupt (Google it for more detailed advice). If that doesn't fix it, maybe comment out all code and then start uncommenting it bit by bit until it crashes.

Comment: Yes I've done that to current workbooks at this time, awaiting for those workbooks to run through and see if there is anymore. We have about a couple of these workbook have this error a day. The question is, why only a few a day when we run over 100 workbooks a day?

Comment: Why is it attempting to load symbols for the VBE if you're only opening an Excel workbook? Is there a `Workbook_Open` handler in the target file? The only reason it *should* be trying to load VBEUI.DLL is if the VBE is asserting a debugger.

Comment: Is this 64Bit Office running on 32bit windows?  Can you try using 32bit Office instead?  We’re the previous builds you tested that worked 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: @RBarryYoung this is 32bit.

Comment: @Comintern yes there is an workbook open. This is not just an excel workbook, it is a workbook with macros/sheets complex stuff. This same workbook works fine most of the time, we just can't figure out why it's happening on random workbook files.

Comment: I'd start looking at the `Workbook_Open` handlers then. The last line of the error (Access violation writing location 0x00000000) is the only other real clue - something is trying to assign to a null address.

Comment: but the thing is, the workbook doesn't even get loaded to the point of workbook open event. I've tried to open it in safe mode no success. I've tried to open it without the workbook open event startup no success either, almost like the WHOLE excel workbook is corrupted but from what?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the managed code. If there is no VBA code running before you get the error, and you're using .NET?, why is this question tagged VBA?

Comment: @Comintern I'm not using .NET, when the excel workbook not responds, i can debug it, i use visual studio to debug the error and that is the error it shows in VS.

Comment: So if you're attaching to a failing Excel process that you *didn't* open programmatically, how do you know the `Workbook_Open` handler isn't running? That still raises the question of why it is trying to load symbols for the VBE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180065/discussion-between-thisguyjustneedshelp-and-comintern).

Comment: the workbook does not talk to VS. I'm only using VS to debug the error that occurred from EXCEL!